# How to store replicate runs in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a function (call it random_func) that generates random numbers according to some rules using parameters. I'm trying to repeatedly call that function and store the results in a dataframe.

```
df <- lapply(c(1,2,3,4,5), FUN = function(x) replicate(100, expr = random_func(n=10, param=x)))
```

Right now, the output is a list of 5 vectors each with 100 elements. What R voodoo do I need to do in order to get it to look something like:

```
param, result
1, 5
1, 6
1, 8
...
5, 10
```

Comment: Maybe `sapply` instead of `lapply`. But in your case `sapply` returns a `matrix` not a df.

Comment: Use `unlist` to turn them into a single vector, then put them in a data frame: `result = data.frame(param = rep(seq_along(df), times = lengths(df)), result = unlist(df))`.

Comment: That's the voodoo I'm talking about! :)  Is there a better way to do this in the first place instead of messing with my df output?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(42)
do.call(rbind,         #rbind results for different x together
    lapply(c(1,2), FUN = function(x)
        data.frame(param = x,   #will be recycled
            result = do.call(what = c,  #concatenate results of replicate
                replicate(n = 2,
                    expr = rnorm(n = 3, mean = x),  #replace with random_func
                    simplify = FALSE)))))  #when FALSE, replicate returns list
   # param    result
# 1      1 2.3709584
# 2      1 0.4353018
# 3      1 1.3631284
# 4      1 1.6328626
# 5      1 1.4042683
# 6      1 0.8938755
# 7      2 3.5115220
# 8      2 1.9053410
# 9      2 4.0184237
# 10     2 1.9372859
# 11     2 3.3048697
# 12     2 4.2866454
```

Answer (score 1):

#### rerun and map_df solution

from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
```

Random function

```
random_func <- function(n, param) {
                    rnorm(n)+(param*10)
               }
```

#### solution

```
myfun <- function() {
             df <- 100 %>% 
                rerun(x=10, y=1:5) %>%
                map_df(~data.frame(param=.x$y, result=random_func(n=.x$x, param=.x$y)))
         }
```

#### Output

```
df <- myfun()
head(df)

  param   result
1     1 10.15325
2     2 19.52867
3     3 30.08218
4     4 40.06418
5     5 48.39804
6     1 11.00435
```

Additional validation

```
df %>%
   group_by(param) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(result))

  param     mean
1     1 10.00634
2     2 20.03874
3     3 30.11093
4     4 40.06166
5     5 50.02632
```

#### Performance

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfun())

    expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 myfun() 65.93166 66.80521 69.42349 68.5152 69.57185 90.77295   100
```